# c++ function matching and constness

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a question regarding function matching. consider this code:

main.hpp:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(double = 1.0)
  {
    std::cout << "Foo constructor\n";
  }
  operator double()
  {
    std::cout << "Foo double\n";
    return double(1.0);
  }
  operator int()
  {
    std::cout << "Foo int\n";
    return int(1);
  }
};

void Bar(Foo &f)
{
  std::cout << "Bar Foo\n";
}

void Bar(int)
{
  std::cout << "Bar int\n";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
double d;

Bar(Foo(d));
```

output:

```
Foo constructor
Foo int
Bar int
```

however if i change `void Bar(Foo &f)` to `void Bar(const Foo &f)`, output changes to

```
Foo constructor
Bar Foo
```

I'm not sure why `const` causes to call `Bar(Foo)` instead of `Bar(int)` even though `Foo(d)` is not `const`.

Comment: Because a rvalue (temporary) `Foo(d)` cannot bind to a `Foo&` while it can to `const Foo&`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo(d)` is a rvalue/temporary, it can't bind to a `Foo&` but it can bind to a `const Foo&` which is why it can call `void Bar(const Foo &f)`, `const Foo&` is a better match here than conversion to `int` and then `Bar(int)` because that requires an extra user-defined conversion. When using `Foo&` the compiler isn't allowed to call `Bar(Foo&)` but it sees that it can make a conversion to `int` and then call `Bar(int)`, so it does.